# Bash grep IP from command output

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working with fleetctl and kubectl and would like to extract an IP from `kubectl get pod app-etcd`:

```
POD        IP           CONTAINER(S)   IMAGE(S)                     HOST                               LABELS          STATUS    CREATED   MESSAGE
app-etcd   10.10.0.1                                               k8s-socius-node-1/100.100.100.100   name=app-etcd   Running   3 days    
                        app-etcd       xyz/etcd-discovery                                                      Running   3 days
```

The closest I got to get the IP address is:

```
kubectl get pod app-etcd | grep -Eo '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
```

But this gives me both IP addresses (10.10.0.1 and 100.100.100.100); I only want/need the first one to run `sed` over a config file afterwards.

How do I get only the first address to store it in a variable for further processing?

Comment: With `grep -m1`, only the first match will be printed. A better solution is often to have the program output its result in machine-readable form; these days, that would be JSON, traditionally, XML was popular as well.

Comment: Is your desired IP address always in 2nd column?

Comment: @tripleee -m1 doesn't work for me (grep on OS X). I'd love to have the output in JSON, but well .... I'm not the editor of kubectl.

Comment: @tripleee went through the docs and somebody really put some thought in the program. There's JSON and XML and other output formats! --output json

Comment: Maybe post that as an answer, and accept it so that  this question no  longer comes up as unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kubectl offers json output with `--output / -o`:

```
kubectl get -o json pod app-etcd | jsawk 'return this.status.podIP'
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you use `awk` to get the second column output like

```
kubectl get pod app-etcd | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: That's the whole line: IP
10.104.0.3
tleyden5iwx/etcd-discovery

Comment: @Patrick, I believe you want only the first IP (10.10.0.1) per your post descripton and the above command in answer does gives the exact output. Is thee a specific reason for the downvote?

Comment: I tried awk before as I've seen it in various examples. But awk in this case outputs 3 lines: IP \n 10.104.0.3 \n tleyden5iwx/etcd-discovery. That's not the solution to the problem.